# Genymotion бесконечно что-то оптимизирует (optimizing app)?

Tags: android, genymotion

При запуске эмулятора 5й версии и более, Genymotion бесконечно что-то оптимизирует так и не запуская его. В чем тут может быть дело?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну оптимизирует он (скорее даже не сам эмулятор, а ОС Android 5.x - так происходит на всех устройствах с лолипопом на борту при первом запуске) приложения для работы с ВМ Art.

Для ускорения и оптимизации работы, новой виртуальной машине требуется проделать некоторую предварительную работу,о подробностях которой много писали в свое время, если вам вдруг интересно станет.

Почему же эмулятор не может закончить эту работу - вопрос туманный.
Может ему еще времени надо, может конфигурация оборудования не подходящая для эмулирования Art, например [есть мнение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31141619) , что ему нужна активация `Intel Virtualization Technology` в BIOS. Вообще требования к оборудованию следующие:

1. OpenGL 2.0 capable video card, with an up-to-date driver;
2. VT-x or AMD-V capable CPU, enabled in BIOS settings;
3. RAM memory: at least 2GB;
4. Screen resolution greater than 1024 x 768 pixels;
5. Free space on hard disk: at least 100MB.

В частности пункт 2 - поддержка  процессором и активная виртуализация.

может еще какая проблема.

Comment: Проблема решена! Спасибо! Решение: Intel Virtualization Technology в BIOS - разрешить.